# Is there any option include Java Generics Type in proguard prop file

Tags: java, proguard

I have a configuration class in spring boot project. It has the List of Tenant object class member in that class. I don't find the 'private List<Tenant> tenant' after obfuscating the class using Proguard.

How to configure in proguard configuration file to get an expected result?

```
<b>Code</b>

public class MTConfig {

  private List<Tenant> tenant;

  .....

}

Verifying the class file after obfuscation using proguard;

<u><i>Actual Result :</i></u>

public class MTConfig {

  private List tenant;

  .....

}

<b>Expected Result:</b>

"
public class MTConfig {

  private List<Tenant> tenant;

  .....

}
"
```

Comment: you want  all `List<?>` objects un-obfuscated ? or just one tanent object ?

Comment: Thanks Khalid Shah for your quick response. just this List<Tenant> tenant class member. not all members and selected class members.

Answer (score 1):

put this in your `progurad.conf` file

```
-keepclassmembers class com.yourproject.MTConfig** {
    private java.util.List<com.yourprojectPath.Tenant> tenant;
 }
```

and use

```
-keepattributes Signature
```

> The "Signature" attribute is required to be able to access generic
>   types when compiling in JDK 5.0 and higher.

Comment: Thanks Once again. I tried and added in proguard.conf file. Facing below error while running the maven build.. "[proguard] java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Reference to wildcard must be a number (com/yourprojectPath/Tenant).. "

Comment: @arm   `com/yourprojectPath`  means your actual Class path. replace with your actual path of MTConfig class.

Comment: I changed to 'private java.util.List<1> tenant' to resolve the exception. It worked fine. Thanks!

Comment: @arm welcome :) accept it as answer or upvote it if your problem is solved :)